# Drush unable to untar Drupal 8

Tags: 8, drush

Something has happened to my Drush and I've run out of ideas.

It is unable to untar drupal-8.0.6.tar.gz. I discovered this while trying to update a site but it's nothing to do with the site because it happens when I try to download drupal into an empty directory.

The weird thing is that it works with Drupal 7. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. Drush is installed globally with Composer.

```
ross@ross-laptop:~/drush-test$ drush --version
 Drush Version   :  8.0.5 

ross@ross-laptop:~/drush-test$ drush -v dl drupal
Loading version_control engine.                                                                                                                                   [notice]
Loading package_handler engine.                                                                                                                                   [notice]
Executing: wget --version
Loading release_info engine.                                                                                                                                      [notice]
Downloading release history from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/8.x                                                                            [notice]
Executing: wget --version
Executing: wget -q --timeout=30 -O /tmp/download_filec9M7oQ https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/8.x
Downloading project drupal ...                                                                                                                                    [notice]
Executing: wget -q --timeout=30 -O /tmp/download_fileW1T2nI https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-8.0.6.tar.gz
Downloading drupal-8.0.6.tar.gz was successful.                                                                                                                   [notice]
Md5 checksum of drupal-8.0.6.tar.gz verified.                                                                                                                     [notice]
Executing: tar  -C /tmp/drush_tmp_1460638235_570f921b1a52f -xzf drupal-8.0.6.tar.gz
Unable to untar /tmp/drush_tmp_1460638235_570f921b1a52f/drupal-8.0.6.tar.gz.                                                                                   [error]
Error downloading drupal                                                                                                                                          [notice]
Command dispatch complete                                                                                                                                         [notice]
ross@ross-laptop:~/drush-test$
```

Now trying Drupal 7

```
ross@ross-laptop:~/drush-test$ drush -v dl drupal-7
Loading version_control engine.                                                                                                                                   [notice]
Loading package_handler engine.                                                                                                                                   [notice]
Executing: wget --version
Loading release_info engine.                                                                                                                                      [notice]
Downloading release history from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/7.x                                                                            [notice]
Executing: wget --version
Executing: wget -q --timeout=30 -O /tmp/download_file9HXrRX https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/7.x
Downloading project drupal ...                                                                                                                                    [notice]
Executing: wget -q --timeout=30 -O /tmp/download_filelb2ETq https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7.43.tar.gz
Downloading drupal-7.43.tar.gz was successful.                                                                                                                    [notice]
Md5 checksum of drupal-7.43.tar.gz verified.                                                                                                                      [notice]
Executing: tar  -C /tmp/drush_tmp_1460638348_570f928cdd995 -xzf drupal-7.43.tar.gz
Executing: tar -tzf drupal-7.43.tar.gz
Executing: svn info /home/ross/drush-test
Executing: bzr root /home/ross/drush-test
Project drupal (7.43) downloaded to /home/ross/drush-test/drupal-7.43.                                                                                         [success]
Project drupal contains:                                                                                                                                       [success]
 - 3 profiles: minimal, testing, standard
 - 4 themes: garland, stark, bartik, seven
 - 47 modules: drupal_system_listing_compatible_test, drupal_system_listing_incompatible_test, toolbar, simpletest, image, openid, trigger, path, search,
forum, translation, statistics, locale, color, rdf, syslog, contact, menu, book, update, help, php, blog, filter, file, tracker, profile, block, dblog, poll,
overlay, taxonomy, shortcut, comment, user, number, field_sql_storage, options, list, text, field, node, system, contextual, field_ui, dashboard, aggregator

Command dispatch complete                                                                                                                                         [notice]
ross@ross-laptop:~/drush-test$
```

It successfully updated a module on my D8 site. The problem just seems to be with D8 core. I've checked permissions. The user I'm logged in as can create files and directories in /tmp.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's a tough one. I just downloaded Drupal 8.0.6 successfully on my machine; it untarred just fine. I can't think of anything that could explain why Drupal 8 wouldn't download, but Drupal 7 would. Well, I can think of one thing -- when I first tried this, Drush told me it was "retrieved from cache".  I ran `drush cc drush` and tried again, and it downloaded from drupal.org and untarred just fine. I might guess that the file was somehow corrupted on download, but (a) Drush checks the checksum, and (b) your debug output above shows that you're getting a fresh download.

Try running `drush -v dl drupal --select --all` and pick some other versions of Drupal 8.  Is it only 8.0.6 that will not untar, or are other releases also broken?

(Sorry for the long non-answer, but this didn't fit well in a comment.)

Comment: Thanks. I know this is weird. I had already tried a few other 8 versions but not quite enough. I followed your command and it works up to  8.0-alpha12. It fails on anything more recent. I've done everything I can think of to make things "clean". I've uninstalled drush by removing from the composer.json, deleted my ~/.drush directory and reinstalled drush. The results are consistent. It stops working for anything more recent than 8.0-alpha12.  This worked a few months ago when I upgraded from rc1 to rc2. I've installed and removed a few things since then but nothing that seems related to this.

Comment: I think I've found it. I'm almost out of disk space on / where /tmp is.

Comment: Ouch! Running out of disk space is tough. It would help if tools gave better error messages when this happens; Drush is not alone in needing improvement in this area.

Answer (score 0):

Oops...

My laptop is almost out of disk space on the partition where /tmp is.  :-)

It downloads successfully but fails when it tries to copy. Each version of Drupal is a bit bigger than earlier versions.